# How to search questions with only one specific tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

I can search question with target using `[target]` but the result questions also include question tagged with other tags.

How to get the question with only one specific tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a dupe of the newer one because I do think they are dupes, but the newer one is an actual feature request, complete with a suggested search operator, so IMHO it's the more valuable of the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The internal Stack Exchange search mechanism does not support this kind of search, however we can use SEDE for that.

I have just written [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/429381/find-questions-with-one-specific-tag), where you put a tag name and get back the latest 5000 questions that have only this tag. (The limit is due to the amount of posts on SO, causing SEDE to crash with timeout if you try to select too many posts.)

For example, [questions on Stack Overflow tagged only with php](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/429381/find-questions-with-one-specific-tag?tag=php).

Just keep in mind, the data there is not live, but updated every Sunday, so you will not see questions posted between last Sunday and the current time.

I have extended this a bit for meta sites, where one of the four [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [support](/questions/tagged/support), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is mandatory. [This query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/573440/get-questions-with-only-a-specific-tag-plus-bug-feature-request-support-discuss) will find all questions on a meta site, tagged with one those four mandatory tags plus the given desired tag, e.g. for the [tags tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/573440/get-questions-with-only-a-specific-tag-plus-bug-feature-request-support-discussi?tag=tags) here on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify how many tags a question should have on it.

Frankly, we encourage each question to have more than one tag, so I don't really see the benefit of such a feature.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: One benefit is finding questions that need to be retagged, exactly for the reason "we encourage each question to have more than one tag"