# Searching for questions that have ONLY a given tag (i.e. add a range operator for tags)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, search

I was doing a little cleanup in a tag recently, and was wanting to find any questions with *only* that tag, since that often means they weren't tagged very well and are in need of a few more.

Unfortunately, there was no good way in the advanced search to do this. You can exclude a *specific* tag, but there doesn't appear to be a way to exclude *all but one* (or a subset). Also, tags can't be quantified with a range operator like, for example, answers can (i.e. `answers:3` for all questions with 3 or more answers).

Is there a way to do this with the current search that I've overlooked? If not, could a `tags:N` search option be added to narrow down the search based on the number of tags a question has?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273840/307988

Comment: I've tentatively voted to close the older one as a dupe of this one because I do think they are dupes, but this one is an actual feature request, complete with a suggested search operator, so IMHO it's the more valuable of the two.

Comment: Sorting search results by relevance is a reasonable approximation of finding questions having only the given tag - at least on smaller sites. See: [Searching a single tag by relevance bug or by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138089) and [How to find questions having only given tag (and no other tags)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20632) (meta.math.SE). Some SEDE queries are mentioned in [Search for singleton tags on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148977) and [Searching for question having strictly a certain set of tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105548).

Comment: @JasonC: Not sure how I missed those dupes, I did search quite a bit first. It's a shame the only real answer so far has been "Use SEDE". I'd much prefer something built into the search bar that you could easily combine with other options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly positive that there is no way to do this with the advanced search (and I support the addition of a tag count as a search operator, although I don't *strongly* support it as it ideally should be rare and is a relatively unusual use case), however, in the mean time, you can do this through SEDE if you don't mind the data being up to a week old (it's updated weekly), by [using the `Tags` field in `Posts`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/674520), which is a list of tags enclosed in angle brackets:

```sql
SELECT TOP 50
  Id [Post Link], Tags, *
FROM
  Posts
WHERE
  Tags = '<java>'  -- Tag name (case-sensitive) inside <>'s
ORDER BY
  CreationDate DESC
```

You can also do a join on `PostTags` and `Tags` then search by `Tags.TagName` but the query becomes more complex to look for posts with just a single tag.

To make it more reusable you can use a parameter field for the tag name, for example [in this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/674527) just type the tag name in the box below the query then press *Run Query*.

Replace `Tags = '<java>'` with `Tags LIKE '%<java>%'` to get any post with that tag instead of posts with just that tag.

---

Also, if you want to find *any* question with just one tag, regardless of the tag, you can use [a query like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/674538?NumberOfTags=1):

```sql
SELECT TOP 50
  Id [Post Link], Tags, *
FROM
  Posts
WHERE
  LEN(Tags) - LEN(REPLACE(Tags, '<', '')) = 1 -- # of <'s = # of tags
ORDER BY
  CreationDate DESC
```

An alternate trick in the case of just one tag is `Tags NOT LIKE '%><%'`.

---

More complete docs on the SEDE schema can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).